# cl::vector vs std::vector: different iterator behaviour

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, opencl

**EDIT:** Added debugging output with memory locations as suggested by PlasmaHH.

I don't understand the different behaviour of the cl::vector<> in the C++ bindings for OpenCL. Consider the following code:

Header `Top.hpp`:

```
class Top {
public:
    void setBool(bool b);
    bool getBool();
private:
    bool status;
};
```

Source `Top.cpp`:

```
#include "Top.hpp"   

void Top::setBool(bool b) {
    std::cout << (void*)this << " setBool("<< b<< ")\n";
    status = b;
}

bool Top::getBool() {
    std::cout << (void*)this << " getBool() returns " << status << std::endl;
    return status;
}
```

Use the above:

```
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR

#include <iostream>
#include "CL/cl.hpp"
#include "Top.hpp"

using namespace cl;
using namespace std;

cl::vector<Top> js;

int main() {
    js.push_back(Top());
    js[0].setBool(true);
    cout << js[0].getBool() << endl;
    for(cl::vector<Top>::iterator i = js.begin(); i != js.end(); ++i) {
        (*i).setBool(false);
    }
    cout << js[0].getBool() << endl;
}
```

With `__NO_STD_VECTOR` the std::vector is overridden. The output is

```
0x6021c0 setBool(1)
0x6021c0 getBool() returns 1
0x7fffae671d60 setBool(0)
0x6021c0 getBool() returns 1
```

So the location returned by the iterator is definitely wrong.

Using the above with the `std::vector` (and changing the namespaces to `std` of course) however gives the expected output:

```
0x1be0010 setBool(1)
0x1be0010 getBool() returns 1
0x1be0010 setBool(0)
0x1be0010 getBool() returns 0
```

This iterator is acting differently, but it's supposed to replace the std::vector to avoid compatibility issues. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try adding something like `std::cout << (void*)this << "setBool("<< b<< ")\n";` to your setBool function (and similar to getBool) to see what is going on, and where things are set, if at all. This way you can see if it is iterating at all, or stuff is "pointing" to the wrong elements etc.

Comment: In any case, the `std::vector` behaviour is what I'd expect. I can't imagine why the `cl::vector` does something so strange...

Comment: @Xeo: yes `std::vector` is expected. 
@PlasmaHH: Indeed, the object returned by the iterator has a different memory address, so it's not returning my object and setting my `false` somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an expert at OpenCL by any stretch of the imagination, but I'm interested so I went over to [CUDA/OpenCL Computing](http://openclcomputing.com/opencl-c-bindings). I appears that their * operator returns a copy rather than a reference:

```
00706         T operator *()
00707         {
00708             return vec_[index_];
00709         }
```

Whereas the (first, non-const) vector [] operator returns a reference:

```
00621     T& operator[](int index)
00622     {
00623         return data_[index];
00624     }
00625   
00626     T operator[](int index) const
00627     {
00628         return data_[index];
00629     }
```

Try iterating through the vector directly (using the old "int i = 0, ...") and see if that gives different results. If so, you might want to put in a bug report (check first) since this is unexpected behavior for the * operator.

Comment: I can confirm that the array-like approach (excuse the lack of appropriate terms) works (as in the sample above `js[0].setBool(false)`).

Comment: Erp! I should have noticed that! Well, I'd say to contact AMD (or whoever did your library) and ask if that's on purpose. It certainly isn't how I'd expect it to act.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an Nvidia chip, so I bet they're just waiting for my bug report... But I'll have a look.

Comment: Can somebody confirm this behaviour on an AMD OpenCL device?

Comment: I was actually looking to see where NVidia got their C++ bindings from, but I couldn't find that info on their site. It sounds like they're using the AMD C++ bindings, in which case it should duplicate. That should be noted somewhere in your cl.hpp file (at the top of?) ... I would hope.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the addresses I suspect that this is a 64-bit build and that the cl vector's iterator's `operator*` is returning by value rather than by reference, not allowing access to the original element. As an experiment you could try using the `->` operator instead `i->setBool(false);` to see if that's implemented sanely.

Comment: The `->` operator is not working, the compiler complains: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘cl::vector<Top, 10u>::iterator’. I'm a bit lost interpreting this.

Comment: @rdoubleui: That means the iterator hasn't overloaded `operator->` it seems.