# Why should I use cl::vector?

Tags: c++, opencl, std

At the moment I'm trying to work on some projects in OpenCL to understand how it works and how it can help me do my calculations faster. Most of tutorials on the internet suggest that one should use cl::vector instead of std::vector.

Why?

Whats the difference between them and why cl::vector is better for OpenCL development?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081956/clvector-vs-stdvector-different-iterator-behaviour

Comment: @MarounMaroun I actually found it before asking, but it really only states that iterator behavior is different, not answers why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenCL C++ specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.1.pdf) mention this in section 5 (page 60):

> While C++'s Standard Template library provides an excellent resource
> for quick access to many useful algorithms and containers, it is often
> not used due to compatibility issues across different toolchains and
> operating systems, among other reasons. The OpenCL C++ API uses
> vectors and strings in a number of places and by default will use
> std::vector and std::string, however, the developer has ability to not
> include these.
>
> The C++ API provides replacements for both std::vector
> (cl::vector) and std::string (cl::string) or the developer has the
> option to use their own implementations.

So it seems that there are compatibility issues between various implementations of these standard C++ types and therefore OpenCL provides its own types that are known to work for what OpenCL needs them.

Note however that by default OpenCL sticks to the standard C++ types; to use cl::vector and cl::string you will have to define the macro `__NO_STD_VECTOR` and/or `__NO_STD_STRING`.  These two replacement types should probably not be used for non-OpenCL code, as they provide reduced functionality.  Example: The way I understand it, cl::vector is limited to 10 elements by default and there's no way to resize it beyond that.  A quick test on my linux machine actually silently failed to push_back() more than 10 elements to a cl::vector object.  That's very scary.

Unfortunately I couldn't find more details about which toolchains exactly cause these problems.  I just only started doing OpenCL work, so I can't yet speak from my experience.  But I will try to go with the standard std::vector as much as I can and instead avoid bad toolchains.

Answer (score 0):

Both classes are similar. `cl::vector` does not implement `resize, reserve, insert, erase or swap` (at least in OpenCL 1.1). 
Thus, if you need one of these functions, you'll have to use `std::vector`.